# In an Android ,I am a beginner.I write this code; public void Showmsg(View v)

Tags: android

I write the following code in MainActivity.java.This code is about on the click of the button.
Suppose There is a default text "dhaval" But when I click on the button 'WELCOME' the text shoud be changed like "Hi!This is Dhaval's First App".So I write the onClick of the button the function public void Showmsg()

In this I can't understand why we pass 'View object' as a parameter?

Following code I written:

```
 public void Showmsg(View v)
    {
        TextView tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Hi!This is Dhaval's First App");
    }
```

Comment: Apparently you don't need this parameter. You only need to be on the Activity class.

Comment: if you are not using the view you dont need to pass it to that function. post more of the code because it is not exactly clear where you are calling this

Comment: if you are not using a decent IDE || not knowing Java, then I suggest using it, it helps a lot. IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse, doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Every `onClick` method must have a `View` parameter. This is a reference to the view which was clicked.